# rspec-rails: undefined method `true?' for true:TrueClass after updating to 3.0.0.beta2 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

After updating  rspec-rails from version 2.14.0 to 3.0.0.beta2, all tests that uses `be_true` or be_false fails.

```
 Failure/Error: user.new_record?.should be_true
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `true?' for true:TrueClass
```

Any suggestion? Google returns anything about this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version 3.0, RSpec renamed `be_true` to `be_truthy` and `be_false` to `be_falsey` as documented in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers and discussed in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283.

`be_true` and `be_false` were deprecated in 2.99 and dropped in 3.00 because they didn't *just* match `true` and `false`, respectively and were therefore misleading. The error message you're getting is because absent any specific `be_xxxx` method definition, `be_xxxx` will look for and invoke `xxxx?` on the actual.

Note that if you want to match *just* `true`, you can use `be true` (or `be(true)`).